# Progress bar show under Button

Tags: android

Android studio 3.1

minSdkVersion 21

Here my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="md.dotfinance.tm.android.ui.activity.AddTraderActivity" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/common_gray_color_bg">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/jsonViewToolBar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:title='@{@string/add_trader}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/base"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jsonViewToolBar" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/baseEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quoteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:text="@string/quote"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseEditText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/quoteEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteTextView" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@color/button_gray"
            android:text="@string/start"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteEditText" />

        <include
            layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Here my progress_bar_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/containerProgressBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4777"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But when I start app the progress bar is UNDER button. 
[image]

But I need over button.
How I can do this?

Comment: put your progressbar in a linearlayout and then inclue the file and also define this tag on your include element in xml => app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/startButton" then you are good to go :)

Comment: Not help. Same result.

Comment: `Button`s have `elevation` by default, which will make them appear on top of other views. You can add `elevation` to the ProgressBar or you can change your layout in order to have the button and progressbar not overlap.

Comment: set to button the next attirbutte -   
 android:elevation="2dp" - not help. Same result.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use

> 

of

> android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

and add

> android:elevation="30dp"

to the RelativeLayout tag

Comment: Try to use  "RelativeLayout" )

Comment: it's working fine with ```RelativeLayout``` using elevation

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to hide the progress bar or make it's `visibility="gone"`. Make sure you give it an ID so you can invoke it and hide the other layout with buttons and text views. Then show the progress bar when you process a certain request. Make it invisible!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="handler"
            type="md.dotfinance.tm.android.ui.activity.AddTraderActivity" />

    </data>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/progress_bar_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/common_gray_color_bg">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/jsonViewToolBar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar"
            android:title='@{@string/add_trader}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/baseTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="@string/base"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/jsonViewToolBar" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/baseEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quoteTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:text="@string/quote"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/baseEditText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/quoteEditText"
            style="@style/textViewOneLine"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteTextView" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/min_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
            android:background="@color/button_gray"
            android:text="@string/start"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/baseTextView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/quoteEditText" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: compile error: ***Only one layout element and one data element are allowed